# Python Dataframe color using dictionary in cell

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dictionary that looks like that:

```
{'NAME1': [{'value':'plop','color':'#444444'},{'value':'plop2','color':'#444445'}, ...], "NAME2": [...], ...}
```

I created a dataframe this way:

```
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(<my dictionary>)
```

Which correctly puts the `{'value':...,'color':...}` subdicts in their corresponding cells.

Then, I wanted to color them using the value stored in column and and show their value in the cells. Doing either of these is easy:

Changing the color:

```
df = df.style.applymap(lambda val: val['color'])
```

Changing the text:

```
df = df.applymap(lambda val: val['value'])
```

Still, if I change the value, I can't get the color anymore and if I change the color I now have a Styler object and I don't know how to modify the value of cells in this one.

I am somehow new to Python so I guess there must be a simple solution to that problem but I'm out of idea. Can you please give the most 'elegant' solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem in two steps:

1. Putting my keys in an array
2. Using the format method from the Styler after setting the colors

This gives the following code:

```
keys = ['NAME1', 'NAME2', ...]
df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict({key: <whatever> for key in keys})
df = df.style.applymap(lambda val: val['color'])
df = df.format({key: lambda val: val['value'] for key in keyes})
```